# Brother Printer drivers not getting installed correctly due to broken packages. How to solve this?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, printing, brother

I have a Brother printer HL-L2321D. I tried installing driver installer tool from [here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=in&lang=en&prod=hll2321d_as&os=128).

Earlier, these drivers were not giving two-sided print option. Now, with new Ubuntu install, these drivers are not able to print at all.

Here's my log:

```
You are going to install following packages.
   hll2320dlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
   hll2320dcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
OK? [y/N] ->y

*EDIT: EULA Omitted*

wget -T 10 -nd --no-cache http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/packages/hll2320dlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
--2018-08-17 10:55:39--  http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/packages/hll2320dlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
Resolving www.brother.com (www.brother.com)... 23.32.28.26, 23.32.28.200
Connecting to www.brother.com (www.brother.com)|23.32.28.26|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 35574 (35K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘hll2320dlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb’

hll2320dlpr-3.2.0-1 100%[===================>]  34.74K  --.-KB/s    in 0.006s  

2018-08-17 10:55:40 (5.95 MB/s) - ‘hll2320dlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb’ saved [35574/35574]

*EDIT: EULA Omitted*

Do you agree? [Y/n] ->Y

wget -T 10 -nd --no-cache http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/packages/hll2320dcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
--2018-08-17 10:55:45--  http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/packages/hll2320dcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
Resolving www.brother.com (www.brother.com)... 23.32.28.200, 23.32.28.26
Connecting to www.brother.com (www.brother.com)|23.32.28.200|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 18982 (19K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘hll2320dcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.deb’

hll2320dcupswrapper 100%[===================>]  18.54K  --.-KB/s    in 0.001s  

2018-08-17 10:55:46 (13.9 MB/s) - ‘hll2320dcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.deb’ saved [18982/18982]

Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease            
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu xenial InRelease  
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32ncurses5 lib32z1

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 is to be installed
                Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.18) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
dpkg -x hll2320dlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb /
dpkg -x hll2320dcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.deb /
dpkg-deb: building package 'hll2320dlpr' in 'hll2320dlpr-3.2.0-1a.i386.deb'.
dpkg -b ./brother_driver_packdir hll2320dlpr-3.2.0-1a.i386.deb
dpkg-deb: building package 'hll2320dcupswrapper' in 'hll2320dcupswrapper-3.2.0-1a.i386.deb'.
dpkg -b ./brother_driver_packdir hll2320dcupswrapper-3.2.0-1a.i386.deb
dpkg -i --force-all hll2320dlpr-3.2.0-1a.i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package hll2320dlpr:i386.
(Reading database ... 187592 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack hll2320dlpr-3.2.0-1a.i386.deb ...
Unpacking hll2320dlpr:i386 (3.2.0-1) ...
Setting up hll2320dlpr:i386 (3.2.0-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/hll2320dlpr.postinst: 3: /var/lib/dpkg/info/hll2320dlpr.postinst: /opt/brother/Printers/HLL2320D/inf/braddprinter: not found
dpkg -i --force-all hll2320dcupswrapper-3.2.0-1a.i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package hll2320dcupswrapper:i386.
(Reading database ... 187605 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack hll2320dcupswrapper-3.2.0-1a.i386.deb ...
Unpacking hll2320dcupswrapper:i386 (3.2.0-1) ...
Setting up hll2320dcupswrapper:i386 (3.2.0-1) ...
lpinfo: cups-deviced failed to execute.
lpadmin -p HLL2320D -E -v usb://dev/usb/lp0 -P /usr/share/cups/model/brother-HLL2320D-cups-en.ppd
lpadmin: Bad device-uri scheme "usb".
###############################ls: cannot access '/usr/share/ppd/*.ppd': No such file or directory
#
lpinfo: cups-deviced failed to execute.

0 (I): Specify IP address.
1 (A): Auto. (usb://dev/usblp0)

select the number of destination Device URI. ->1

lpadmin -p HLL2320D -v usb://dev/usblp0 -E -P /usr/share/cups/model/brother-HLL2320D-cups-en.ppd
lpadmin: Bad device-uri scheme "usb".
Test Print? [y/N] ->y

wait 5s.
echo HLL2320D \| lpr  -P HLL2320D
```

Comment: in step 2, I clicked For Ubuntu8.04/8.04.1 and it directed me to "Pre-required Procedure (2). I ran the command "sudo aa-complain cupsd", but the terminal said," aa-complain: command not found.". Sorry, I'm a little new.

Comment: I ran this now, "sudo apt-cache cupsd", and the terminal says :E: Invalid operation cupsd

Comment: These are the results:  sudo apt-get build-dep cups
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81859/discussion-between-maaz-ahmad-khan-and-hello-moto).

Comment: these solutions didn't work